# How to pass string as datetime value in parameterised query

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, datetime

I have a select query. which passes a string as datetime as shown below.

```
string SelectedDate = "16-04-2017";
string query1 = "SELECT * FROM test_details where  selected_date <=  @init ";
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query1, con))
{
    command.Parameters.Add("@init", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(SelectedStartDate);
}
```

Which works well in local system. But when uploading the code to remote serevr it shows error `"System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."`
I have tried below codes too. But shows same issue.

```
command.Parameters.Add("@init", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value =  DateTime.ParseExact(SelectedStartDate, "mm/dd/yyyy", null);
command.Parameters.Add("@init", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value =  SelectedStartDate
```

Comment: Try using DateTime.Parse(string) instead of using DateTime.ParseExact

Comment: You code has dash in the date while your parse has forward slashes : "16-04-2017" and "mm/dd/yyyy"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the conversion of `SelectedDate` to DateTime object. The `Convert.ToDateTime()` is not capable of parsing the given date and also you have given wrong format in the `ParseExact`. So better you try the following:

```
DateTime dtValue = DateTime.ParseExact(SelectedDate, "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
command.Parameters.Add("@init", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dtValue;
```